# glfwWindowShouldClose error

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am currently making a small c++ engine using opengl and glfw and I get a weird error while trying to call the `glfwWindowShouldClose(window)` function here is my code :

```
#include "Engine\Window.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    GLFWwindow* window = 0;
    Window::InitGLFW();
    Window::CreateWindow(window,640,480,"1");

    while (true)
    {
        if (glfwWindowShouldClose(window))//here is the error
        {
            Window::DestroyWindow(window);
            Window::EndGLFW();
            return 0;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Window.h File :

```
#ifndef ENGINE_WINDOW
#define ENGINE_WINDOW

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "GL\glew.h"
#include "GLFW\glfw3.h"

using namespace std;

class Window
{
public:


    static bool InitGLFW();
    static void EndGLFW();
    static bool CreateWindow(GLFWwindow* Window, int Width, int Height, char* Title);

    static void DestroyWindow(GLFWwindow* Window);

private:
    static void error_callback(int error, const char* description);
};



#endif
```

Now the Window.cpp file :

```
#include "Window.h"


void Window::error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    cout << "Error: %s\n" << description;
}

bool Window::CreateWindow(GLFWwindow* Window, int Width, int Height,char* Title)
{
    Window = glfwCreateWindow(Width, Height, Title, NULL, NULL);
    if (!Window)
    {
        cout << "Window or OpenGL context creation failed";
        return 1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(Window);
    return 0;
}

bool Window::InitGLFW()
{
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        cout << "glfw Initialization failed";
        return 1;
    }
}

void Window::DestroyWindow(GLFWwindow* Window)
{
    glfwDestroyWindow(Window);
}

void Window::EndGLFW()
{
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

So as you can see the the program gives me an error when its running not when I compile and the error is:

```
Unhandled exception to 0x56B34B9F (glfw3.dll) in Engine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation when reading location 0x00000014.
```

I assume the variable that `glfwWindowShouldClose` look at is not created?

if you need to know i am running on Windows 10 and I use Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> if (glfwWindowShouldClose(window))//here is the error
> ```

That's because `window` is a NULL pointer.

You initialize it here:

> ```
> GLFWwindow* window = 0;
> ```

and never change it's value again.

This function

> ```
> bool Window::CreateWindow(GLFWwindow* Window, int Width, int Height,char* Title)
> {
>     Window = glfwCreateWindow(Width, Height, Title, NULL, NULL);
>     [...]
> }
> ```

just updates it's local copy of the `Window` variable and leaks the pointer when the function is left.